# How to build multiple nodejs projects that depend on each other

Tags: node.js

I have 37 nodejs projects that depends on each others. About 20 of them are front end SPA, the rest are libs. Is there a way/tool to build them in such a way that if I specify the front end SPA X to be built, then X and all of its dependencies are built but not the whole 37 projects.
In maven, I can do it with the "--projects X --also-make" flags but I don't know about nodejs world.

Comment: In Node.js world, you keep all the deps close together. You don't make them separate. If you happen to separate out libs, you usually "install" them using the package manager. Whatever libs you install, must not be using its dependents as dependencies. If somehow your apps need to communicate to each other, you use a message broker which carries out messages from one app to another.

Comment: Considering this: X, and Y projects are both SPA built on vuejs. They both need to use a vue component provided by Z which is a separated project. Y also needs another vue component provided by K which is another separated project. All X, Y, Z, K are in the same git repository so at commit A we want to build X so I expect Z to be built then X. 
From your suggestion, i guess you mean to link Z to X and Y so that when building X Z is also built (i dont know how, please advise). But then this approach slow down the build because if 20 projects need Z then it will be built 20 times.

Comment: First of all, X and Y shouldn't go in the same repo. The Vue library itself is separated into many parts. There are community libraries (I guess [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) is such an example) which don't care about how Vue operates. Everything is separate. The libraries will be built separately and imported via [ES module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) or [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) syntax.